# sortable jQuery rearrange background array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I have an item list with text input along with other things, and this list is sortable by jQuery-ui.

the job of the text input is to give more options to the item,

so I create an array that contains all the options, it goes something like this:

```
var options = new Array();
$('.optionInput').keypress(function(event){
 -- some code for enter press --
 var index = $('.inputs .inputOption').index(event.target);
 if(typeof options[index] === 'undefined') options[index] = new Array();
 options[index][options[index].length] = $(event.target).val();
});
```

other code show them along with the item.

so my problem is the array links to the items by their position, the array index is the position.

I tried to use sortable events 'start' and 'update' and I got the position of the start and the new position but i got stuck in how to proceed from there...

What is the best way to rearrange the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to that! It works but it seems to me there must be a better way

maybe someone has a better idea??

```
inputBox.sortable({
    handle: '.sortHeader',
    start: function(event, ui){
        sortPositionOld = $('.inputs').index(ui.item);
    },
    update: function(event, ui){
        var sortArr = new Array();
        var sortPositionNew = $('.inputs').index(ui.item);
        var temp;
        for(var index in options){
            if(index == sortPositionNew) temp = sortPositionOld;
            else if(index < sortPositionNew && sortPositionOld < sortPositionNew && index >= sortPositionOld) temp = parseInt(index)+1;
            else if(index > sortPositionNew && sortPositionOld > sortPositionNew && index <= sortPositionOld) temp = parseInt(index)-1;
            else temp = index;
            sortArr[index] = options[temp];
        }
        options = sortArr;
    }
});
```